# TSQL Dynamic Pivot function without aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I spent a lot of time searching google to find a solution for my problem.
I have a list like this

It's a result from a query like this:

```sql
SELECT        VBELN, POSNR, PATENT_ID
FROM            table
GROUP BY POSNR, VBELN, PATENT_ID
```

```sql
  VBELN     POSNR   PATENT_ID
    0090139195  000100  PIST-1
    0090139195  000100  PIST-2
    0090139195  000100  PIST-3
    0090139195  000100  PIST-4
    0090139195  000100  PIST-5
    0090139195  000100  PIST-6
    0090139195  000100  PIST-7
```

One billing position have 1 material and this material can have 0 to around 20 patent_ids.

To compare the combination of Patent_IDs I need to pivot this extract to a list like this

```
VBELN       POSNR   Patent 1    Patent 2    Patent 3    Patent 4    Patent 5    Patent 6    Patent 7
90139195    100     Pist-1      Pist-2      Pist-3      Pist-4      Pist-5      Pist-6      Pist-7
```

In our actual solution we have a very buggy way with 50 (!) views. (not created by myself)
This views are part of a big stored procedure and the result is wrong.
I don't want to have a look in all this views and fix it.

So I evaluate the pivot function in TSQL and the idea looks good to me.
Unfortunately I don't get the result I want...

My result is like this:

```sql
VBELN       POSNR   Patent 1    Patent 2    Patent 3    Patent 4    Patent 5    Patent 6    Patent 7    
0090139195  000100  NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

TSQL is

```sql
select vbeln, posnr, patent1, patent2, patent3, patent4, patent5, patent6, patent7 
from
(
  select  VBELN, POSNR, PATENT_ID, Key_pos
  from tablename
  where VBELN = N'0090139195'
) d
pivot
(
  min(Key_pos)
  for patent_id in (patent1, patent2, patent3, patent4, patent5, patent6, patent7 )
) piv;
```

Where condition is applied for testing purposes only...

Maybe one of you have an idea for me how to fix this stuff.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why does this need to be dynamic if you know the maximum number of columns you will need?

Answer (score 1):

I would use conditional aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
SELECT VBELN, POSNR,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN PATENT_ID END) as PATENT_ID_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN PATENT_ID END) as PATENT_ID_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN PATENT_ID END) as PATENT_ID_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 4 THEN PATENT_ID END) as PATENT_ID_4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 5 THEN PATENT_ID END) as PATENT_ID_5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 6 THEN PATENT_ID END) as PATENT_ID_6,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 7 THEN PATENT_ID END) as PATENT_ID_7
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VBELN, POSNER ORDER BY PATENT_ID) as seqnum
      FROM table
     ) t
GROUP BY POSNR, VBELN;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,
thank you very much. Works great for me! :-)